# Im new to Bitcoin and want to know if storing wallet on my hard drive could corupt it?

Tags: wallet

Will storing a wallet on my hard drive increase the risk of corruption to the drive?

Answer (score 1):

It will increase the risk of corruption as much as storing any other file of the same size on your hard drive, which is to say that there is no additional risk of corruption for having a wallet. Wallet files aren't special in some way that makes them more prone to damaging a hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if the wallet.dat could become corrupted while it's on your hard drive, well it's possible if you had a hard drive failure, sudden power loss, lightening strike and so on.
It's always good practice to keep several wallet backups, one of them being in a different physical location if possible.
However you also need to make sure that you keep regular backups, and make sure all the copies are current.  The standard keypool of 100 will get used up on 100 transactions, so keeping a backup every 50 transactions or expanding the keypool will help keep you safe.

Comment: Core wallets are now HD so there is no need to make regular backups if you only care about access to the coins. If you also care about the meta data like transaction and address labels then you do need to make regular backups.